# Spring Boot MVC MessageSource defaultEncoding does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, character-encoding

Simple Spring Boot Web Application.
Configs snippet:

```
    @Bean
    public MessageSource validationMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("ValidationMessages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(validationMessageSource());
        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }
```

I set a `defaultEncoding` as `UTF-8` . I have `ValidationMessages.properties` file that is encoded in UTF-8 (my IntelliJ says so, notepad++ says so) and contains different characters.

I have a simple web page (created using Freemarker). There is some static UTF-8 text on that page and it is displayed correctly.

And I want to see correct error messages when I submit a form located on that page, but when validation fails ( JSR-303/JSR-349 validation) I can see someting like `Ð¾Ð±Ð¾Ð²ÑÐ·ÐºÐ¾Ð²Ðµ Ð¿Ð¾Ð»Ðµ. min 2, max 15 ÑÐ¸Ð¼Ð²Ð¾Ð»ÑÐ²` that's a message from `.properties` but it's wrongly encoded!

Here is the page (simplified: no divs, css , js, etc.):

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>ShareMyCar</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    </head>
    <body>
       <form action="/registration" method="POST">
           <@spring.formInput path="modelObj.name" />
           <@spring.showErrors "<br>"/>

           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />            
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

What else I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Can you post your page source?

Comment: @ThrawnCA done.

Comment: Have you tried adding a HTML4 charset declaration? `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` Shouldn't be needed for HTML5, I know, but worth a test.

Answer (score 0):

Java automatically assumes ISO-8859-1 encoding on localization bundles.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)

To make it work, either save the file as ISO-8859-1, or use escape sequences such as \u1234.

Comment: `/**
  * Set the default charset to use for parsing properties files.
  * Used if no file-specific charset is specified for a file.
  * <p>Default is none, using the {@code java.util.Properties}
  * default encoding: ISO-8859-1.
  * <p>Only applies to classic properties files, not to XML files.
  * @param defaultEncoding the default charset
  */
 public void setDefaultEncoding(String defaultEncoding) {}` I thought this should help

Comment: Take a look at the source for org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource, you will see it's using java.util.ResourceBundle to load the .properties.

Comment: but I create `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` bean in my app and I think that one is used to load properties and that one is configured to use UTF-8

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Perhaps debug and step into the ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource to see what it's doing? You mentioned intellij.. I know with eclipse, .properties files are saved as ISO-8859-1 even if the project is configured as UTF-8.. Maybe check if intellij does something similar?

Comment: [In Java SE 9, properties files are loaded in UTF-8 encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/intl/internationalization-enhancements-jdk-9.htm#JSINT-GUID-974CF488-23E8-4963-A322-82006A7A14C7)